# MySql query to order by existence in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables (products, product_info and specials)

```
products(id, created_date)
product_info(product_id, language, title, .....)
specials(product_id, from_date, to_date)
```

product_id is foreign key which references id on products

When searching products I want to order this search by products that are specials...

Here's my try

```
SELECT products.*, product_info.* FROM products
INNER JOIN product_info ON product_info.product_id = products.id
INNER JOIN specials ON specials.product_d = products.id
WHERE product_info.language = 'en'
AND product_info.title like ?
AND specials.from_date < NOW()
AND specials.to_date > NOW()
ORDER BY specials.product_id DESC, products.created_at DESC
```

But the result is only special products..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If not every product is in specials table, you should do a LEFT JOIN with specials instead and put the validations of the dates of specials in the ON CLAUSE. Then you order by products.id but put the specials first, by validating it with a CASE WHEN:

```
SELECT products.*, product_info.*
FROM products
INNER JOIN product_info ON product_info.product_id = products.id
LEFT JOIN specials ON specials.product_d = products.id
                  AND specials.from_date < NOW()
                  AND specials.to_date > NOW()
WHERE product_info.LANGUAGE = 'en'
  AND product_info.title LIKE ?
ORDER BY CASE 
    WHEN specials.product_id IS NOT NULL THEN 2
    ELSE 1
    END DESC,
  products.id DESC,
  products.created_at DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT products.*, product_info.* FROM products
INNER JOIN product_info ON product_info.product_id = products.id
INNER JOIN specials ON specials.product_d = products.id
WHERE product_info.language = 'en'
AND product_info.title like ?
AND specials.from_date < NOW()
AND specials.to_date > NOW()
ORDER BY specials.product_id DESC,products.id DESC, products.created_at DESC
```

Comment: No the same result as before

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
   products.*, 
   product_info.*
FROM products
JOIN product_info ON product_info.product_id = products.id
LEFT JOIN specials 
   ON specials.product_d = products.id AND NOW() BETWEEN specials.from_date AND specials.to_date
WHERE product_info.LANGUAGE = 'en'
  AND product_info.title LIKE ?
ORDER BY 
   specials.product_id DESC NULLS LAST,
   products.product_id DESC,
   products.created_at DESC;
```

Since you don't have specials for all products, you have to do an outer join instead of an inner.